# Trying to find a function for graph

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

[image: graph]

Hello,
I am trying to write an equation for this graph but I cannot.
I have drawn the graph myself so it may not be a good one, sorry for that.

Until now I have tried to find a link between this graph and exponential graph but I could not.
Do you have any idea to help me?

Comment: If $y$ is constant after $x=100$, you will need a piecewise function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Try a function of the fom $a+\frac{b}{x}.$